# How would I randomly rotate and scale each sprite created from a class in pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pygame2

I am trying to clean up my code, and am moving scripts to different files. I want put my image (in this case, meteors) in random places, with random rotation and size. I can get it to go to random places, but just can't figure out how to scale and rotate it randomly.
This is what I used to use which gave me what I wanted, a meteor in a random size and rotation in a random place.

```py
import pygame, random
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 720))

pic = pygame.image.load('assets/meteor.png').convert_alpha()
rotimage = pygame.transform.rotozoom(pic, random.randint(0, 359), random.randint(1, 2)) 
random_x = random.randint(0, 1280)
random_y = random.randint(0, 720)
while True:
    screen.blit(rotimage, (random_x, random_y))
    pygame.display.update()
```

It worked fine like this, but I have no clue on how to apply this in another file. My second python file looks something like this.

```py
import random
import pygame

display_width = 1280
display_height = 720
rotation = random.randint(0, 359)
size = random.randint(1, 2)
pic = pygame.image.load('assets/meteor.png')
pygame.init()


class Meteor(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pic
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (x, y)


all_meteors = pygame.sprite.Group()

for i in range(3):
    new_x = random.randrange(0, display_width)
    new_y = random.randrange(0, display_height)
    pygame.transform.rotozoom(pic, rotation, size)  # How do I put this in
    all_meteors.add(Meteor(new_x, new_y))    #this only allows x and y
```

My new main file looks something like this

```py
while True:
    meteors.all_meteors.update()
    meteors.all_meteors.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.update()
```

How would I get the image to randomly rotate and scale within the meteor file?

Comment: So to make sure I understand this correctly, the pic you are referencing in `self.image = pic`, is the picture of the meteor.  And what you want is for each meteor to have the same pic, but rotated or scaled differently?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think creating a Meteor object first, then updating it's pic before adding it to all_meteors should do the trick.  Perhaps replace the for-loop with something like this:

```py
for i in range(3):
    new_x = random.randrange(0, display_width)
    new_y = random.randrange(0, display_height)
    met = Meteor(new_x, new_y)
    rotation = random.randint(0, 359) # Some line here to pick a random rotation
    size = random.randint(1, 3)       # some line here to pick a random scale
    met.pic = pygame.transform.rotozoom(met.pic, rotation, size)  # How do I put this in
    all_meteors.add(met)    #this only allows x and y
```

Note: I forget if `pygame.transform.rotozoom()` is an in-place operation.  If so, then replace `met.pic = pygame.transform.rotozoom()` with `pygame.transform.rotozoom()` -- remove the `met.pic =`.

---

Another way to go about this would be to adjust the class directly:

```py
class Meteor(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        
        self.rotation = random.randint(0, 359)
        self.size = random.randint(1, 2)
        self.image = pic
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotozoom(self.image, self.rotation, self.size)
        
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (x, y)
```

Comment: The first suggestion did not work for me, even while replacing `met.pic = pygame.transform.rotozoom()` with `pygame.transform.rotozoom()`, but the second suggestion worked like a charm! Thank you for your time and support! Marking as an answer